# How to add new features in ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 to an existing project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, nuget

So Microsoft has released a new update for the Web Tools.
[Web Tools 2012.2 Scot Gu Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx)
However the way it is designed, it will not update the current project, I would like to update a current project and am unsure on how to go about doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you expect to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

You can update all of the javascript libraries that are added by default in the new templates using NuGet. You can add in the new features, such as SignalR and Web API Tracing using NuGet too.

Basically, NuGet is your friend. :)

Comment: Yup, it's all just NuGet packages and you can add all the new features from 2012.2 into any existing ASP.NET project.

Comment: So I realize that nuget would be the place to do it, but there are a bunch of new features, such as the new help page that need to be updated. What I was hoping for is a list of nuget commands to do a complete update.

Comment: To be honest, if you know the name of the features that you want, then just search NuGet for them. It won't take more than a couple of minutes to do.